# How to invoke a modal using JS Jquery for multiple a tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four a tags (two acting as a button and the other two as basic links).

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" class="myBtn btn btn-default">M-Soft</a>
<a href="http://www.hp.com" class="myBtn btn btn-default">HP</a>

<a href="http://www.google.com" class="myBtn ">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".myBtn").click(function() {
                $("#ConfirmBtn").attr("href", $(this).attr("href"));
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
                return false;
            });
        });
```

The first three a tags can invoke the modal and successfully redirect to their respective hrefs if a confirm button is clicked. The last a tag goes straight to its embedded href without invoking the modal first (note: because there is no class attribute within this a tag).

Question: I need to know if it's possible to add multiple a tags without having to write class for each of them, and still be able to invoke a modal and redirect after clicking a confirm button.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Why can't you just add `myBtn` class to every link which you want to trigger the modal with?

Comment: Instead $(".myBtn") you can use $("a") and add rest of your required logics.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. @ Zoltán Tamási I was trying to find a way of not having to add myBtn to each and every a tag since the project that I'm doing involves dozens or a tags. @Shiv I did tried replacing $(".myBtn") with $("a"), it works well up to the point of invoking the modal. However when I click the confirm button it doesn't redirect me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. You can select every `a` elements by the `"a"` selector. Then in the `click` handler you can check whatever you want, for example existence of classes, etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("myBtn")) {
            $("#ConfirmBtn").attr("href", $(this).attr("href"));
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            return false;
        }
        // do whatever else you want...
    });
});
```